# How safe is to use SQLite database as data exchange format?

Tags: sqlite, security

SQLite webpage [is recommending](https://www.sqlite.org/appfileformat.html) SQLite as "excellent application file format". How robust is SQLite against invalid database files? Could malicious user create a corrupted database file that would cause remote code execution or is it something that database is actively tested and proteced against?

I'm worried that it would be much easier to create malicious file in this format than lets say xml or json file. This seems important if Sqlite were to be used as data exchange format.

Comment: None of your users should ever have access to a database of any format.  Format alone cannot protect data.  Exchanges should always go through an intermediary that validates both user and data.

Comment: @duffymo I'm talking about using SQLite as data exchange format - it's not possible to use it this way without giving users access to physical file.

Comment: I'm suggesting that you shouldn't use it this way.  If you insist, good luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/testing.html) says:

> There are numerous test cases that verify that SQLite is able to deal with malformed database files. These tests first build a well-formed database file, then add corruption by changing one or more bytes in the file by some means other than SQLite. Then SQLite is used to read the database. In some cases, the bytes changes are in the middle of data. This causes the content of the database to change while keeping the database well-formed. In other cases, unused bytes of the file are modified, which has no effect on the integrity of the database. The interesting cases are when bytes of the file that define database structure get changed. The malformed database tests verify that SQLite finds the file format errors and reports them using the SQLITE_CORRUPT return code without overflowing buffers, dereferencing NULL pointers, or performing other unwholesome actions.

Of course, this cannot protect against somebody putting wrong data into the file, or against your program behaving unexpectedly when it reads unexpected data from the database.